# Select only complete entries by x and y status

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have one table holding two messages, `x` and `y`. The user sends `X` before sending `Y` and the columns are updated with `x sent` and `y sent`. The user can N/A these messages if they do not need to send `x`, but need to send `y`.

I need to select *only* the messages that have not been *completed* as in both `x` and `y` equal `N/A` or `SENT`. This will make much more sense if the table is laid out.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
name varchar(20)
, x varchar(10)
, y varchar(10));

INSERT INTO myTable (name, x, y) 
VALUES 
('JIM', 'X SENT', 'Y N/A'),     -- considered complete
('JEFF', 'X N/A', 'Y N/A'),     -- considered complete
('BOB', 'X SENT', 'Y SENT'),    -- considered complete
('GEO', 'X SENT', 'Y ON-GO'),   -- incomplete/on-going y
('LEO', 'X N/A', 'Y ON-GO')     -- incomplete/on-going y

-- show only complete entries

SELECT *
FROM myTable 
WHERE (X <> 'X N/A' or X <> 'X SENT') 
    AND (Y <> 'Y N/A' or Y <> 'Y SENT')

DROP TABLE myTable;
```

Running the SELECT query returns all results, including completed messages, while in my brain it should return only the last 2 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your where clause:

```
WHERE (X <> 'X N/A' or X <> 'X SENT') AND 
      (Y <> 'Y N/A' or Y <> 'Y SENT')
```

Translates to (using boolean logic):

```
WHERE NOT(X = 'X N/A' AND X = 'X SENT') AND
      NOT(Y = 'Y N/A' AND Y = 'Y SENT')
```

`X = 'X N/A' AND X = 'X SENT'` always evaluates to `FALSE` since `x` can't be equal to both strings (same for `y`).

So in effect this short circuits to

```
WHERE NOT(FALSE) AND NOT(FALSE)
```

->

```
WHERE TRUE
```

So this will select all rows. What you probably meant to write is:

```
WHERE (X <> 'X N/A' AND X <> 'X SENT') OR 
      (Y <> 'Y N/A' AND Y <> 'Y SENT')
```

Results:

```
+------+--------+---------+
| name |   x    |    y    |
+------+--------+---------+
| GEO  | X SENT | Y ON-GO |
| LEO  | X N/A  | Y ON-GO |
+------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: @Strawberry boolean logic will do that to you ;-)

Comment: @TT lol you beat me to it but took a different path. Well done :)

Answer (score 1):

Not being as familiar with operators in MS SQL as I am with MySQL it appears that you are trying to compare strings using operators (<,>) that were meant for integers instead to compare numerically.

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE X NOT IN ('X SENT','X N/A') OR Y NOT IN ('Y SENT','Y N/A')
```

This method lets you add more items to the arrays to search for if you need to add more in the future. You could also reverse this to check for whether or not X and Y are in an array that you want to search for like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE X IN ('X SENT','X N/A') OR Y IN ('Y SENT','Y N/A')
```

This would give you the opposite result and show you which results fall within your sent criteria.

Here is an image of the sqlfiddle:
[image: SQLFiddle Example]

Comment: Also comparing for inequality with `<>` is ANSI SQL. SQL Server also supports `!=` which isn't ANSI SQL.

Comment: @TT - thanks for the info, I will remember that for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just list the combinations you want:

```
( x = 'X SENT' and y = 'Y N/A' ) or
( x = 'X N/A' and y = 'Y N/A' ) or
( x = 'X SENT' and y = 'Y SENT' )
```

constitute all of the complete entries. Adding `not( )` around that gives you the incomplete entries.

The important part is that you are checking the value *pairs* for `x` and `y`, not checking the `x` value and then checking the `y` value.